# Xampp can't access htdocs when using local IP

Tags: android, apache, xampp

I'm trying to get my android app to access the MySQL database i have setup on my xampp server via lan, but when i use my pc's local ip i am unable to access the PHP scripts on my htdocs folder. I get an error 404. I tried accessing them with postman and the same thing happens, i get an error 404. This is my android code if it's any help:

```
public class OrderingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ordering);

    Log.d("lmao", "starting function");
    getItems();
}

RequestQueue requestQueue;
ArrayList<String> names;
ArrayList<Integer> prices;
String showUrl = "http://192.168.0.17:1234/phpmyadmin/upickss/showBar.php";

public void getItems(){

    Log.d("lmao","im alive");
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,showUrl,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                Log.d("lmao", "trying");
                JSONArray drinks = response.getJSONArray("drinks");
                for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject drink = drinks.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = drink.getString("name");
                    names.add(i, name);
                    int price = drink.getInt("price");
                    prices.add(i, price);
                }
                Log.d("lmao",names.get(0));
            }catch(JSONException x){
                System.out.print(x);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
            Log.d("lmao","error");

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended practice , as the link you provided to the app is deemed harmful and inaccessible therefore the 404 error , the only alternative I can suggest is to rather host the Database on free hosting sites , that we will not give you 404 error .

Or rather Run this app on the emulator replace the ip address with 10.0.2.2 i.e
http://10.0.2.2/phpmyadmin/upickss/showBar.php

you may also need to provide the port no , in that case

http://10.0.2.2:[port no]/phpmyadmin/upickss/showBar.php